# Swift Inheritance problem with "Abstract Class" (Protocol workaround) due Override

Tags: swift, inheritance, scope, singleton, abstract-class

So the thing is: Swift doesn't have "abstract" classes. The workaround for that was using a protocol and an extension. So what I did was write the one abstract method and all the variables I have in the protocol. In the extension I then wrote all the default methods I have, which also includes a init() method.

Afterwards I made a class which is inheriting/implementing that protocol. But since I want to make that class a final singleton class, I have to override the init() method and make it private. And because it is a protocol and not a class, I can't call something like super.init().

What exactly is going to happen? And is there no better workaround for abstract classes?

### Edit: requestValueFor() is part of a template method

```
protocol Categorie {
    private final var multiplyer: Float;

    private final let MAX_VALUE: Float;

    private final var actualValues: Dictionary<DistrictName, Float>;

    public func requestValueFor(district: DistrictName) -> Float;
}

extension Categorie {

    internal init() {
        initValues();
    }

    private func initValues() {//setting actualValues and maxValue}
    private func setMultiplyer() {//binding to some ui}
}
```

---

```
final class Culture: Categorie {

    private static var instance: Categorie?;

    private init() {}

    class func shared() {
        if (instance == nil)
        {
            instance = Culture();
        }
        return instance;
    }

    func requestValueFor(district: DistrictName) -> Float {
        <#code#>
    }
}
```

Comment: It's because protocols imo are not designed to have default implementation or variables declared inside of them. The questions is, does my 'private init' leave me without the default init I declared in the protocol because it is a override? And since I can't call super.init because it is a protocol and not a class I basically lost all my setup that I would want to happen by default. And the semi-colon, it's just a better programming style imo. Code is more readable. There is a good reason other languages use it...but I get your problem. It is not the apple swift coding guideline

Comment: Yes I am. If I were to implement every class by its own, I would have to copy past all the methods and variables I have in my protocol for each final class I wanna have. That's why you would usually use a super class. And I don't really think it has much to do with design making the final class a singleton at the end. It would be easy in any other language as you would just use a abstract class and call the superclass initializer in the final class. But yeah. Since there is no abstract class I can only use a protocol, and since that is not a class per se I can't call a initializer